# Trying to use a new line character in a regex is causing a "new line" in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, regex

I'll include a few images to get my point across here.

So what I'm trying to do is take ALL punctuation off of a word that comes out of an array. But it doesn't seem to be working and the biggest problem is that my `\n` and `\r` are acting as new lines.

Images:
So my Regex Code

[image]

Is becoming this

[image]

When I run it in a browser. And then I get the error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

The missing / makes sense because the rest of the regex is now two lines below!

Using RegExr shows that it should be working

[image]

I'm sure it's dreadfully simple, but I just can't seem to spot my error!
If someone could explain the error of my ways, I would appreciate it, as I am terrible with RegExpressions! The other similar questions I've read on here have pointed out missing brackets, missing escape characters, etc.

I even tried escaping my escaped characters! ie. `\\n` and `\\r`, but that just left behind the two extra slashes each on a new line.

In case it helps: This JavaScript code is being echo'd out from PHP, but it works if I take out the `\n` and `\r`, so it shouldn't be a PHP issue.

Hopefully this is enough info, if there is something else I can add to clarify please comment!

Comment: Why not use `\u000A` and `\u000D` (`\x0A` / `\x0D`)? Try.

Comment: Wow... that worked perfectly... any input on what's going wrong with the way I had it? Shouldn't it have worked my way?

Comment: I made the images appear in the question. And just one more note: there is no need escaping `^`, `*` and `.` in the expression since they are used inside the character class (and `^` is not the first symbol in it). Please check my answer and decide what must be matched and edit accordingly.

Comment: *"it shouldn't be a PHP issue"* - but I'm pretty sure it is. It's not a JS or regex issue because it looks like the individual \ and n characters are not being sent to the browser: PHP is treating them as a newline and echoing that.

Comment: That makes sense @nnnnnn , changing it to the hex codes worked, so problem solved, but I appreciate you pointing out the reasoning behind the error!

Comment: There must be some way to escape the \ in PHP so that it actually does send a single \ followed by an n to the browser, but I'm not a PHP guy so I don't know. (If it were Java or C# I could help...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `\n` and `\r` are escape sequences and are interpreted literally as linefeed and carriage return symbols. They break the JS code (in this case, the literal regex notation).

To avoid that data corruption, when you send a regex pattern from one system to another, you'd better rely on the hex representation of the characters.

Use `\u000A` (or `\x0A`) for a line feed and `\u000D` (`\x0D`) for the carriage return.

One more remark: in the expression, there is one unescaped `-` that creates a range. I guess it is done on purpose, but still, a detail worth reporting. `,-\/` will match `,`, `-`, `.`, and `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using the hex codes worked perfectly, and I'll consider it a lesson learned for future reference! (also thank you for editing my question to make the images work)

Comment: Also, unrelated (and I'll delete this comment once answered) but how did you fix the images in my post? What was I missing?